# Split the given text based on pattern java

Tags: java, regex, split

Below is my text

```
This is my first java Program. I am new to java program. but my program is successfully running without any. issues. Thanks to all
```

It should split like

```
This is my first java Program.
I am new to java program. but my program is successfully running without any. issues.
Thanks to all.
```

the regex should take the below pattern

```
1.dot
2.followed by space
3.followed by capital letter word(not lowecase)
```

I tried this

1. `\\.\\w[A-Z]`
2. `\\.\\s\s[A-Z]`
3. `\\.(?!\\w)`

But failed to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
String text = "This is my first java Program. I am new to java program. but my program is successfully running without any. issues. Thanks to all";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)\\s+(?=[A-Z])");
String[] lines = pattern.split(text);
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Output:

```
This is my first java Program.
I am new to java program. but my program is successfully running without any. issues.
Thanks to all
```

Comment: I've changed the quantifier of your middle whitespace, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Mena, For which case?

Comment: You hade `\\s+` (greedy) instead of `\\s+?` (reluctant). With 1 whitespace only (as in OP's example) your `Pattern` would not match the input text so the `split` array would be empty.

Comment: @Mena, I know the meaning of `?`. Without `?`, the code produce same result.

Comment: AARGH. Sorry my bad. Reverting (too early in the morning for this).

Answer (score 0):

Use the String.split() method to split your string (returns a array).

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) to learn about java's regular expression.